# ObjC - Automatic View Rotation

Tags: iphone, autorotate

My fellow students and me coded a objective-c program for iPhone.
But we have a big problem:

Our App is coded in Portrait-mode, but 2 or 3 Views should be displayed in Landscape-mode (directly).
We activated Landscape autorotation in these views, but, if we open one of these views now, we get Portrait again and it only turns into Landscape, when we turn the device.

(Already on our test-device, no problem of the IOS-simulator!)

Can anybody help us please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was using

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

in my ViewController and presenting it with ***presentModalViewController***.
This forces the View to stay in landscape.

Comment: thanks! presentModalViewController solved our problem!
now i have the problem, that i have no navigation-bar in my landscape-view..what can i do?

Comment: You probably have to add a own NavigationController to the view that is presented in landscape.